# TypeError when trying to create a model instance

Tags: python, django

I have a project where I need to create a Django command to upload multiple images at a time. I have a base class `Image` that defines the file, and subclass `Icon` that associates a word and a description to the icon.

My issue is that I get an error when I call `Icon.objects.create()`. It works in a single upload context, but not here in the bulk uploader. What should I do about it?

*models.py*

```py
class Image(TimestampedModel):
    """
    Abstract model containing an image, a hash of that image, and operation methods.
    """
    class Meta:
        """
        The metaclass defining its parent as abstract.
        """
        abstract = True

    # Static variables
    RELATIVE_PATH = 'img'
    BLOCK_SIZE = 2**16

    # Attributes
    image = models.ImageField(
        blank=True, null=True, default=None, upload_to=RELATIVE_PATH)
    _hash = models.BinaryField(
        _('MD5 hash'), editable=False, null=True, default=None, max_length=16)


class Icon(Image):
    """
    Image file associated with a word, a descriptor, and (for verbs) tense.
    """
    # Static variables
    TENSE_CHOICES = [
        (None, 0),
        ('1', 1),  # present
        ('c', 2),  # present participle
        ('p', 3),  # past
        ('pp', 4),  # past participle
    ]
    BLOCK_SIZE = 2**12

    # Attributes
    word = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    descriptor = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=32)
    tense = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(
        blank=True, null=True, default=None, choices=TENSE_CHOICES)
    is_approved = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

*bulk_uploader.py*

```py
class BulkUploader:
    """
    Class defining a utility method for uploading multiple icons.
    """
    @classmethod
    def save(cls, filepath, word, descriptor, tense=None):
        filename = filepath.split('/')[-1]
        with open(filepath, 'rb') as f:
            bytes_str = b''
            for buffer in iter(partial(f.read, Icon.BLOCK_SIZE), b''):
                bytes_str += buffer

            breakpoint()
            icon = Icon.objects.create(
                word=word,
                descriptor=descriptor,
                tense=tense)
            icon.image.save(filename, ContentFile(bytes_str), save=False)
            icon.save()
```

*Debug output*

```py
> /home/matt/Repositories/my_project/utils/bulk_uploader.py(28)save()
-> icon = Icon.objects.create(
(Pdb) n
> /home/matt/Repositories/my_project/utils/bulk_uploader.py(29)save()
-> word=word,
(Pdb) 
> /home/matt/Repositories/my_project/utils/bulk_uploader.py(30)save()
-> descriptor=descriptor,
(Pdb) 
> /home/matt/Repositories/my_project/utils/bulk_uploader.py(31)save()
-> tense=tense)
(Pdb) 
> /home/matt/Repositories/my_project/utils/bulk_uploader.py(28)save()
-> icon = Icon.objects.create(
(Pdb) 
TypeError: join() argument must be str, bytes, or os.PathLike object, not 'NoneType'
> /home/matt/Repositories/my_project/utils/bulk_uploader.py(28)save()
-> icon = Icon.objects.create(
(Pdb)
```

**Edit**

*upload.py*

```py
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand, CommandError
from api.dictionary.utils.bulk_uploader import BulkUploader


class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = 'Uploads icons in a given directory based on its part of speech format.'

    def add_arguments(self, parser):
        parser.add_argument('part_speech', type=str)
        parser.add_argument('directory', type=str)

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        try:
            BulkUploader.upload(options['part_speech'], options['directory'])
        except Exception as exc:
            raise CommandError(exc)

        self.stdout.write(self.style.SUCCESS('Upload successful.'))
```

Comment: Please show the whole traceback. Where does the error come from inside the Django code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. I had a `post_save` signal receiver that was being triggered at this line:

```py
icon = Icon.objects.create(word=word, descriptor=descriptor, tense=tense)
```

so my solution was to disconnect then reconnect to the signal.

```py
post_save.disconnect(Image.post_save, sender=Icon, dispatch_uid='0')

icon = Icon.objects.create(word=word, descriptor=descriptor, tense=tense)
icon.image.save(filename, ContentFile(bytes_str), save=False)

post_save.connect(Image.post_save, sender=Icon, dispatch_uid='0')

icon.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the management command?,  are you connected to the DB?. If you are running this outside of Django,  please use django.setup(). Try and change the script to a management command and use python manage.py.

Comment: Yeah, the management command itself seems to work fine, but it calls `BulkUploader` and throws an error there. I'll add the command code in just a moment.

Answer (score 0):

On your model you have the following field:

```py
_hash = models.BinaryField(
    _('MD5 hash'), editable=False, null=True, default=None, max_length=16
)
```

One thing to note here is that a `BinaryField` is a *string-based* field and the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#null) explicitly advises against using `null=True` on string-based fields. Furthermore you set `default=None` which is really redundant (Django will pass `None` as the default if you don't specify it anyway) and is in fact what is breaking your code. Likely internally some code is called which is trying to call `join` on this fields value, hence giving you an error. Normally this fields default value would have been an empty byte `b''` but you have set it as `None`. In fact you have also set `default=None` on other fields too, I would advise you to remove that since it is not useful.

Also the fact that you have set `editable=False` (which again is the default for this kwarg for a `BinaryField`, so this is redundant) mystifies me because you aren't setting a value to this field at creation of the instance and this means that you won't be able to set it's value later on either making the field useless.

Considering all of these you should change your fields definition to:

```py
_hash = models.BinaryField(_('MD5 hash'), editable=True, max_length=16)
```

Comment: From [Model field reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/) `Field.editable` If False, the field will not be displayed in the admin or any other ModelForm. They are also skipped during model validation. Default is True.

Comment: @MattMcCarthy as per the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#binaryfield) `BinaryField` field will set `editable=False` by default. Also setting `editable=False` means you literally cannot change it's value unless you go and change it internally (if you search on this topic you will find various ugly hacks to modify the value of fields with `editable=False`) which is very tedious. There are better ways to not have a field be in a form (You most likely want to set this value later as you have not set it at creation).